# Stop execution of finalizedBy task, or only execute follow-up task on a condition

Tags: gradle

I'm using the `com.google.cloud.tools.appengine` gradle plugin, which has a task `appengineDeploy`.

I have two tasks that configure the `appengineDeploy` task before executing it. My current solution looks something like that:

```
task deployTest() {
    doFirst {
        appengine.deploy {
            version = 'test'
            ...
        }
    }
    finalizedBy appengineDeploy
}


task deployProduction() {
    doFirst {
        appengine.deploy {
            version = '7'
            ...
        }
    }
    finalizedBy appengineDeploy
}
```

Now I wanted to add a security question before the `deployProduction` task is executed, like this:

```
println "Are you sure? (y/n)"
def response = System.in.newReader().readLine()
if (response != 'y') {
    throw new GradleException('Task execution stopped')
}
```

The problem is, by defintion the `finalizedBy` task is executed even if my task throws an exception, and that is exactly the opposite of what I want.

I can't change it to `appengineDeploy dependsOn deployTest` and call `appengineDeploy` as I have two tasks with different configuration.
And I can't change the `appengineDeploy` task as it comes from a plugin.

Is there any other way I can either stop the execution of `appengineDeploy`, or use something other than `finalizedBy` to execute that task after my deploy task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the answer from thokuest a bit (thanks for the help!), to prevent executing any tasks inbetween.
I created it as extension method since I needed it more than once:

```
ext.securityQuestion = { project, task ->
  println "Are you sure you want to execute ${project.name}:${task.name}? (y/n)"
  def response = System.in.newReader().readLine()

  if (response != 'y') {
    project.tasks.each {
      if (it != task)
        it.enabled = false
    }
    throw new GradleException("Execution of ${project.name}:${task.name} aborted")
  }
}
```

and my task now looks like this:

```
task deployProduction() { task ->
  doFirst {
    securityQuestion(this, task)
  }

  finalizedBy appengineDeploy
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to leverage [`onlyIf`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:onlyIf(groovy.lang.Closure)) to decide whether to execute the task, for example by examining a project property.

Here's a litte demo, given that task `appengineDeploy` is a task contributed by a plugin (see comment for details):

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
}

ext {
    set('doDeploy', false)
}

appengineDeploy.configure {
    onlyIf {
        project.ext.doDeploy
    }
}

task deployTest() {
    doFirst {
        println 'deployTest()'
        project.ext.doDeploy = true
    }
    
    finalizedBy appengineDeploy
}


task deployProduction() {
    doFirst {
        println 'deployProduction()'
        
        println "Are you sure? (y/n)"
        def response = System.in.newReader().readLine()
        
        if (response == 'y') {
            project.ext.doDeploy = true
        }
    }
    
    finalizedBy appengineDeploy
}
```

Another option is to disable the task, which goes like this:

```
task deployProduction() {
    doFirst {
        println 'deployProduction()'

        println "Are you sure? (y/n)"
        def response = System.in.newReader().readLine()

        if (response != 'y') {
            project.tasks.appengineDeploy.enabled = false
        }
    }

    finalizedBy appengineDeploy
}
```

Comment: I can't do the first option, as the `appengineDeploy` task comes from a plugin that I have no control over.  
The second option seems to work, although it still executes every task up to `appengineDeploy`. It's not optimal, but at least it prevents it from execution.

Comment: @stschmitt `onlyIf` can be also applied to tasks contributed by plugins. I updated the answer with `appengineDeploy.configure { }`.

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know you could configure external tasks. The last remaining nuisance is that it will still run all tasks up to appengineDeploy, which are quite a bit. But at least it won't execute the one that matters.